# How to return Dialog.Delegate in Amazon Alexa SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

A few of my Intents for my Alexa app require certain slots. The Alexa skills builder makes this easy. I can mark a slot as required and set what Alexa should ask in order for the user to provide the information for the slot. The thing is that as a developer, you have to tell Alexa with your lambda that you want Alexa to handle the slot filling.

Reading the documentation, I get to this part:

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/dialog-interface-reference#details

It states

> If the dialog is IN_PROGRESS, return Dialog.Delegate with no updatedIntent.

How do I do this? In my lambda I have

```
  @Override
  public SpeechletResponse onIntent(final IntentRequest request, final Session session)
      throws SpeechletException {

    Intent intent = request.getIntent();
    String intentName = (intent != null) ? intent.getName() : null;

    if ("AddTwoNumbers".equals(intentName)) {
      if (!request.getDialogState().equals("COMPLETED")) {
          return new DelegateDirective();
      } else {
       handleAdditionIntent();
      }
    } else { // handle other intents}
    }
```

Their code sample doesn't seem too helpful either.

```
} else if (intentRequest.dialogState != "COMPLETED"){
    // return a Dialog.Delegate directive with no updatedIntent property.
} else {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue the other day and I got the solution based on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45681399/826246). Here's the slightly modified version that works for me in version `1.5.0` of Alexa Skill Kit. Hope this helps. You might want to handle the `IN_PROGRESS` state differently if you have more than 1 slot to fill. This code here is only designed for 1 slot.

```
     if (speechletRequestEnvelope.getRequest().getDialogState() != IntentRequest.DialogState.COMPLETED)
        // 1. Create DialogIntent based on your original intent
        DialogIntent dialogIntent = new DialogIntent(speechletRequestEnvelope.getRequest().getIntent());

        // 2. Create Directive
        DelegateDirective dd = new DelegateDirective();
        dd.setUpdatedIntent(dialogIntent);

        List<Directive> directiveList = new ArrayList<>();
        directiveList.add(dd);

        SpeechletResponse speechletResp = new SpeechletResponse();
        speechletResp.setDirectives(directiveList);
        // 3. return the response.
        speechletResp.setNullableShouldEndSession(false);
        return speechletResp;
    }
```

Comment: Amazons support for Alexa development is beyond terrible. I appreciate the help. Looks like the big thing I was missing was the call to `speechletResp.setNullableShouldEndSession(false);` Cheers!

Comment: I can't agree more... the documents are very abstract and does not have concrete example for java